# Oracle database connection for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, identity

I'm trying to make a token-based authorization in my Web API service, planning to store identity tables in my Oracle database.

I know there are two ways of accessing the database - via Oracle ManagedDataAccess or Oracle DataAccess. I've downloaded managed version for Entity Framework 6.

Here is the part of my `web config`:

(*i've modified credentials and string path, just assume that they are correct and i CAN connect WITHOUT Entity Framework - but only with unmanaged DataAccess*)

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
        <dataSources>
            <dataSource alias="Test" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)))" />
        </dataSources>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" 
         providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=login;Password=pass;Data Source=Test" />
    <clear />
    <add name="OraAspNetConString" connectionString=" " />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="v13.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
                  type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

And that's the part of `dbContext` - `OnModelCreating` method should force identity to use my selfprepared tables (or I hope it would, haven't got a chance to test them):

```
 public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
 {
     public AuthContext() : base("Test")
     {
     }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // MUST go first.

         modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MY_SCHEME"); // Use uppercase!

         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");
         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
    }

    public static AuthContext Create()
    {
        return new AuthContext();
    }
}
```

So... when I'm using connection string with ManagedDataAccess:

```
<add name="Test" 
     providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
     connectionString="User Id=login;Password=pass;Data Source=Test" />
```

I'm getting the error :

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

When I'm turning to unmanaged version like this :

```
<add name="Test" 
     providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" 
     connectionString="User Id=login;Password=pass;Data Source=Test" />
```

I'm getting an error that Entity Framework couldn't find any `dbContext` named `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`.

In my other projects I'm using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`, but typing `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` in my connection string - and it works just fine!

The simple question - how do I connect to Oracle with EF6? Via managed and unmanaged data access? (because there is no nuget for the unmanaged framework
version)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear answer for you but following may help to find the root cause.

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` and `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` use different methods to resolve TNS aliases, I assume there is the problem.

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` checks following:

1. data source alias in the `dataSources` section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file (i.e. `machine.config`, `web.config`, `user.config`).
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

whereas `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` is looking for `tnsnames.ora` file in these locations:

1. Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN`
2. Registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN`, resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN`
3. Folder `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`
4. Current directory (which can be different to directory where your application is located)
5. Folder where your application is located